# What is the best way to store string? SharedPreferences Set Collection or Files?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have to store some data (string) in my Android app and I'm a dilemma. What is better solution ? Use Set Collection and keep it at `SharedPreferences` or I should save data to `File` and when I need it I have to read data from file and put it for example on `ArrayList`.

Comment: I want display data from SharedPreferences or file in listview so I use for it ArrayList

Comment: yes got it. srry I didn't read the question carefully before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the quantity & complexity of the data. There is no straight answer to your question.

General approach: If the data are not too sensitive, small in quantity and more frequently used then you should go with SharedPreferences.

If your data is quite large lets say few hundred KBs of String then you should go with File.

Answer (score 0):

*SharedPreferences* ultimately stores data into a file. The advantage of using *SharedPreferences* is that, the data is stored as a key value pair and can be retrieved easily using a key.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to store.

Use **SharedPreferences** when you want store simple, prmitive data. Keep in mind that SharedPreferences will be available only for your app, so anothers apps cannot get data from it.

Use **File** when you have more complex data. You have to take care about how file is available to others. If you put it in sdcard root directory for example it will be available for everyone. If you put it in app package it will behave like SharedPreferences.